# Creating AWS A record using `change-resource-record-sets`: RRSet with DNS name domain.com. is not permitted in zone \047domain.com\047

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, aws-cli

I have the following code:

```
  project_record_batch='{
    "Comment": "Testing creating a record set",
    "Changes": [{
      "Action": "CREATE",
      "ResourceRecordSet": {
        "Name": "domain.com",
        "Type": "A",
        "TTL": 120,
        "ResourceRecords": [ { "Value": "18.xxx.xxx.xxx" } ]
      }
    }]
  }'

  aws route53 change-resource-record-sets \
    --hosted-zone-id "/hostedzone/Z..." \
    --change-batch "${project_record_batch}"
    --region eu-west-2
```

it returns the following error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidChangeBatch) when calling the ChangeResourceRecordSets operation: 
[RRSet with DNS name domain.com. is not permitted in zone \047domain.com\047.]
```

I've tried:

- Making the `--hosted-zone-id` just `Z...`,
- Saving the record set to a file and using `--change-batch file://record-set.json`,
- Attaching a trailing `.` to the `Name` (i.e., `domain.com.`)
- Combinatorial of the above

What am I doing wrong?

---

Also just tried the following for the batch payload:

```
project_record_batch='{
     "Comment": "Testing creating a record set",
     "Changes": [{
       "Action": "CREATE",
       "ResourceRecordSet": {
         "Name": "domain.com.",
         "Type": "A",
         "AliasTarget": { 
            "HostedZoneId": "Z...",
            "DNSName": "18.xxx.xxx.xxx",
            "EvaluateTargetHealth": false
         }
       }
     }]
   }'
```

which gave the following:

```
An error occurred (InvalidChangeBatch) when calling the 
ChangeResourceRecordSets operation: [Tried to create an alias that 
targets 18.xxx.xxx.xxx., type A in zone Z..., 
but the alias target name does not lie within the target zone, 
Tried to create an alias that targets 18.xxx.xxx.xxx., type A in 
zone Z..., but that target was not found, RRSet 
with DNS name domain.com. is not permitted in zone 
\domain.com\047.]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that when programmatically creating the DNS hosted zone, I misquoted the variable for the domain name, hence the weird `\047` stuff, which is an ASCII backslash character code, probably to escape said quotes on the AWS server-side. It ended up coming out as `'domain.com'`, instead of `domain.com`. This seemed to cause a lot of trouble with other commands.

tl;dr make sure you don't get burned by shell quoting issues when using `aws cli`